# Export CSV list with all specific files in directory - with their "path"

Tags: powershell

I am currently running the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir1 -recurse -include *ending.csv |
  Sort-Object fullname |
  Select $CurrentDate,Path,FullName,Name,CreationTime,Length,Chosen |
  Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Force -NoTypeInformation $dir2
```

`$dir1` and `$dir2` are the source / destination paths. 
Now the script just creates a CSV file that lists all files that have an ending according to what I specified along with some other parameters of the files.

I'd also like to have a column that contains the "path without the file" for the file. So basically the `FullName` without `Name` of the file.

Is there such a cmdlet / command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `Directory` property:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir1 -recurse -include *ending.csv | 
  Sort-Object fullname |
  Select $CurrentDate,Directory,FullName,Name,CreationTime,Length,Chosen |
  Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Force -NoTypeInformation $dir2
```

Comment: Great, that's it! Thank you so much!